# Create Webmin user for an EC2 Instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, ubuntu-12.04

I've setup an Amazon EC2 Instance, using the Ubuntu 12.04 AMI (ubuntu/images/ebs/ubuntu-precise-12.04-amd64-server-20120424 (ami-a29943cb)), and I'd like to get Webmin working (so I can setup a DNS).

After following the installation instructions on Webmin's site, the installer says I can login with any username/pass of a user who has superuser access.

The problem is that the EC2 instance only has 1 user "ubuntu", which can only login using SSH keys -- not a password!

I've tried creating users manually and I can't login as those users (even via SSH), so I think it might be a permission thing provided by the AMI.

Does anyone know the best way around setting up a login to my webmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew Smith is correct, but has an unnecessary step in his suggestion. You don't actually need to login to ssh with a password for Webmin to work; ssh and Webmin are unrelated services. Simply set a password for your root, or sudo ALL capable user, and that will be the way you login to Webmin.

Comment: Just adding a password to the root account worked, I could then login via the url.

Answer (score 4):

Setup password for root with "passwd root" and login as it over SSL. If you want to host website you might try virtualmin.

Answer (score 2):

Create a simple user with password having sudo permissions as shown below. You can login to webmin using this user.

```
sudo useradd -g sudo webmin
sudo passwd webmin
```

Make sure you choose a strong password as this is the sudo user. Refer [here](http://wilddiary.com/install-webmin-on-aws-ec2-server/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the reason you can't log in to the instance with anything other than a key is probably the sshd_config has PasswordAuthentication no

Change that to yes.

Then create a user and a password for that user and it might work.

Comment: This is not necessary. SSH authentication is not, in any way, related to Webmin authentication. Both use PAM on the backend, but the sshd configuration does not apply to Webmin authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Create a webmin user password like so: `/usr/libexec/webmin/changepass.pl /etc/webmin root YOURPASSWORD`. Then you can login as "root" with the password you set without adding a system-wide password to your machine root user.